# how to Consider the alternatives of 'throw and catch'?

Tags: ruby

I'm doing the following Ruby Tutorial http://rubymonk.com/learning/books/4-ruby-primer-ascent/chapters/41-exceptions/lessons/93-throw-and-catch.  One of the exercises asks me to:

> Change the last example to return the found tile from a method called
>   search, instead. search should receive the floor plan as a parameter.

exercise is similar to last example(before exercise) and looks like:

```
candy = catch(:found) do
    floor.each do |row|
    row.each do |tile|
        throw(:found, tile) if tile == "jawbreaker" || tile == "gummy"
    end
    end
end
puts candy
```

there is a hint below exercise:

> Try replacing the 'catch' line with a method definition and the
>   'throw' line with a 'return'.

and i did so:

```
candy = search do
    floor.each do |row|
    row.each do |tile|
      return tile if tile == "jawbreaker" || tile == "gummy"
    end
    end
end
puts candy
```

but received error.  can anyone tell me how to do to get the positive result.  and additional question: why is catch(:found) and different throw(:found, tile) in throw / catch code?

Answer (score 4):

> Change the last example to return the found tile from a method called search, instead. search should receive the floor plan as a parameter.

From this I understand the exercise is to implement a method called search, which receives a floor plan as a parameter. So you need to *implement a method called search*:

```
def search(floor)
```

It should *return* the result to candy, so the calling code should look like this:

```
candy = search(floor)
puts candy
```

Now, all this is left is to implement the method body, which should *return* the result. For it to return the correct result, `row.each` should stop as soon as the predicate (`tile == "jawbreaker" || tile == "gummy"`) is `true`. You can replace it with something else. `find` returns the first element which matches the predicate:

```
row.find { |tile| tile == "jawbreaker" || tile == "gummy" }
```

I will leave the changes needed to the outer loop (`floor.each`) as an exercise to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

My attempts as following are passed exercise specification.

```
 def search( floor)
    floor.each do |row|
      row.each do |tile|
        return tile if tile == "jawbreaker" || tile == "gummy"
      end
    end
end

candy = ->(flr) {
   search(flr)
}

puts candy
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the hint you mentioned, but I guess they want you to try this:

```
candy = floor.each do |row|
  row.each do |tile|
     return tile if tile == "jawbreaker" || tile == "gummy"
  end
end
puts candy
```

for your to receive `LocalJumpError`. Because you can't use `return` here. You can use `break`, but it will only take you from inner cycle, that's why we use `throw`-`catch` to jump out from nested loops.

Answer (score 0):

okay so i did this and it worked for me. the code is pretty self explanatory if you have reached this far in ruby

```
floor = [["blank", "blank", "blank"],
     ["gummy", "blank", "blank"],
     ["blank", "blank", "blank"]]
def search(floor)
floor.each do |row|
row.each do |tile|
  return tile if tile == "jawbreaker" || tile == "gummy"
end
end
end

candy = lambda {|floor| search(floor)}
puts candy.call(floor)
```